# How to return multidimensional array into table and display in jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax

I'm returning multidimensional array from php script to html page via ajax. Now the values are returned correctly in array.I checked it on console.log.

But How do I change each array as a individual array in jquery?

This is how I'm passing form php script

```
$json=array();
array_push($json,array("type"=>$carType,"maker"=>$carMaker,"rate"=>$selectRate));
echo json_encode($json);
```

This is how it's being process in ajax.

```
$("#submit").on("click",function()
    {

          $("#set_setting").submit(function(){            

            data = $(this).serialize()
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "html",
              url: "submit_setting.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
              data: data,
              success: function(data) {
              //hide the form
              $("#set_setting").slideUp("slow");
              //show the result

                  console.log(data);

             $(".the-return").html(data);//how to show in table here?

              }

            });
            return false;

          });

        });
```

console.log(data) outputs as below:

```
[
  {
    "type":["4 wheeler","flying ycar"],
    "maker":["Honda","Audi"],
    "rate":[["2","20"],["2","40"],["2","50"],["0","80"],["0","90"],["0","70"]
  }
]
```

I want to show type, maker and rate as individual table.
Like,

> Type:4 wheeler, flying car **[in select box]**
>
> Maker: Honda, Audi **[in select box]**
>
> Rate: value 2- 20,40,50 [in table]
>         value 0- 80,90,70 [in table]

I know this is a bit complicated. At least if can show each array in different table would suffice but in Jquery.

AFTER EDIT

```
$("#submit").on("click",function()
    {

          $("#set_setting").submit(function(){            

            data = $(this).serialize()
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              url: "submit_setting.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
              data: data,
              success: function(data) {
              //hide the form
              $("#set_setting").slideUp("slow");
              //show the result
              var parse_JSON = function (data) {
                  try {
                       var obj = JSON && JSON.parse(data) || $.parseJSON(data);
                       return obj;

                  } catch (e) {
                       // not json
                       console.log("Can not parse");
                       return false;
                  }
              };
                $.each( obj.type, function( index, value ){
                 console.log(value);
                });
             //$(".the-return").html(me);

              }

            });
            return false;

          });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update v2**
Add this header on top of your PHP script :

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

**Update**:
Your JSON returned is not valid:

```
[
  {
    "type":["4 wheeler","flying ycar"],
    "maker":["Honda","Audi"],
    "rate":[["2","20"],["2","40"],["2","50"],["0","80"],["0","90"],["0","70"]
  }
]
```

The rate key has a missing closing square bracket `[`, It should be:

```
[
  {
    "type":["4 wheeler","flying ycar"],
    "maker":["Honda","Audi"],
    "rate":[["2","20"],["2","40"],["2","50"],["0","80"],["0","90"],["0","70"]]
  }
]
```

As you are expecting **JSON** in return, so, change the **dataType** to **JSON** in your **AJAX** request:

```
$.ajax({
    .....
    dataType: "json",
    .....

    success: function(data) {
       //hide the form
       $("#set_setting").slideUp("slow");

       $.each( data.type, function( index, value ){
             console.log(value);
       });
   }
});
```

You can loop through each element like this, in your **AJAX** callback:

```
$.each( data.type, function( index, value ){
   console.log(value);
});
```

*Notice `type` key here with data array, change it to other keys to iterate over other array elements*

Comment: I tried it and it says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.  Somehow cannot access anything like data.type.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using ?

Comment: @Vani: Can you try filtering data variable from the added method in answer ?

Comment: Did but don't see anything on console.log()

Comment: Did you tried looping on the returned data from this method ?

Comment: yes I did but it says Uncaught ReferenceError: obj is not defined

Comment: @Vani: Please see the updated success callback code, you had to filter the returned data with the parse_JSON function, which you didnt..

Comment: Oh okay and It says Can not parse now. below that another error which is  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: @Vani: Sorry for missing this out, but your JSON has structure error, check the answer, I have added the correct structure as well ..

Comment: sorry for that typo.. in my real code the bracket is present

Comment: Maybe my php is not passing json? because if I change the data type to html then I can see the data string but whne changed to json nothing could see.

Comment: @Vani: Can you try adding content header in your PHP script ?

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following link ,

http://jsfiddle.net/cjc2o55e/ Working code    `

```
'var json_ec = $.parseJSON('{"type":["4 wheeler","flying ycar"],"maker":["Honda","Audi"],"rate":[["2","20"],["2","40"],["2","50"],["0","80"],["0","90"],["0","70"]]}');
var type = '';
var maker = '';
var rate = '';
$.each(json_ec,function(k,v)
       {
           if(k == 'type')
           {
               type = v;
           }
           else if(k == 'maker')
           {
               maker= v;
           }
           else if(k == 'rate')
           {
               rate = v;
           }               
       });
console.log(type);
console.log(maker);
console.log(rate);'
```

`